# Microsoft Graph Calendar API - TargetIdShouldNotBeMeOrWhitespace error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We use Microsoft Graph API's to create a calendar in outlook

Following is the HTTP Request

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/calendars
Content-type: application/json

{
  "name": "My Calendar"
}
```

It was working for the last 2 years. Suddenly it is throwing an error as

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "TargetIdShouldNotBeMeOrWhitespace",
    "message": "Id is malformed.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "78bce863-d6fb-4ea9-b0f8-e5097010cef6",
      "date": "2019-03-23T11:54:34"
    }
  }
}
```

When we searched the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0).
We found the API URL has been changed

1. When was a critical update like this was rolled out which caused breakage in our flows?
2. Is there any official channel/group notifying these changes.

similar question for mail API's [Microsoft Graph API - SendMail http 400 - API url from documentation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306596/microsoft-graph-api-sendmail-http-400-api-url-from-documentation-not-working)

Comment: The URL has always been `/me`, not `/users/me` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @HongOoi We are using this code in production for about two years. It just stopped working from last week. 

Also refer the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306596/microsoft-graph-api-sendmail-http-400-api-url-from-documentation-not-working.

It seems they are also facing the same issue

Comment: Then you were using the wrong URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct URI is `/me`, not `/users/me`. Behind the scenes, `/me` is just an alias for `/users/{id}`. Asking for `/users/me` would be the equivalent of asking for `/users/users/me`.

It sounds like you were making use of an unintended behavior. It stopped working when that behavior was corrected.